# Cordova cli create with proxy

Tags: node.js, cordova, cordova-cli

I want to run

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

but all I get is the base folder structure and the error: connect ETimedOut.

I have set the proxy for node.js and PhoneGap projects get setup fine.
Cordova cli is setup fine so far (can find it in c:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm)

Anything I am missing? (PATH is set to ...npm)

Comment: A few more debugging steps would be helpful.  What does 'cordova -d create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld' show?  What does 'cordova -v' display?

Comment: cordova version: 3.3.1-0.1.2 "cordova create" works after setting all the platform urls to http instead of https. Still the same error pops up when adding platforms like "cordova platform add android". The reply is "Creating android project..." "..cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126 throw e:" "Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project." "at ..check_reqs.js:47:27 ... child_process.js:641:7 ... events.js:98:17 ...child_process.js:735:16 ... child_process.js:948:11 ... events.js:95:17 ... net.js:466:12 ...Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it:

- set the urls platform.js

  ```
  http instead of https.
  ```
- installed ANT and set some environement vars:

  ```
  ANT_HOME c:\dev\apache-ant-1.9.3\
  ANT_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=http://proxy.myAddress.de -Dhttp.proxyPort=3000
  PATH %ANT_HOME%\bin
  ```
- set some additonal Adnroid environment vars:

  ```
  PATH %ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
  ```

Hope this helps others

Comment: where is the platform.js file?