# Can't create a cordova project, proxy issue?

Tags: node.js, cordova, proxy

I'm trying to create a project after installing cordova via the command line : npm install -g cordova. The installation apparently goes well, I don't get errors, except couple of warnings which I don't know the cause :

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node": "0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
C:\Users\SALWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\SALWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
cordova@4.3.0 C:\Users\SALWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, dep-graph@1.1.0, d8@0.4.4, xcode@0.6.7, elementtree@0.1.5, through2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, glob@4.0.6, npm@1.3.4, request@2.47.0, plist@1.1.0, init-package-json@1.3.0, tar@1.0.2, cordova-js@3.8.0)
```

After this, I try to create a project using the following command line : 
`cordova create electionscasa com.geomatic.electionscasa ElectionsCasa`
but then I get this error :

```
Creating a new cordova project with name "ElectionsCasa" and id "com.geomatic.electionscasa" at location "C:\myApp\electionscasa"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED
at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\SALWA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:168:17)
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:199:16)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:272:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at net.js:451:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I've looked for a solution to this problem but I couldn't find any although I think it's related to the proxy ?
So I took a look on the environment variables and didn't find : http_proxy nor https_proxy.. So I added them and set them respectively to :

```
HTTP_PROXY:    http://localhost:8080
HTTPS_PROXY:    https://localhost:8080
```

I re-typed the previous command but still get the same error..
Please help as I'm stuck with this error and can't move forward..
Thanks in advance!

> P.S: I've installed NodeJS beforehand and I'm working on my local machine (not a corporate), under windows 7.

Comment: Hmm, weird.  Are you running through a proxy (control panel / internet options)?  Any chance you could load up wireshark and see which connection gets refused?

Comment: Hi @laughingpine and thanks for your reply. Well when I go to the control panel/internet options the proxy checkbox is unticked! I'm not running through a proxy.. Concerning Wireshark, I'll install it but how could I figure out which connection gets refused ?

Comment: Wireshark could have told us which connection was getting refused, which might have helped -- was just a suggestion :)  Again, still seems like proxy issues (which is strange,) so maybe give this a shot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166539/cordova-cli-create-with-proxy -- to save you some time, platforms.js file is located along this path: node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova

Comment: @laughingpine didn't work for me :(! The thing is I already had those environment variables set.. I don't know what's wrong neither.. It is weird! How can I work around this issue?

Comment: Like since I'm not running through a proxy why do I get this error? Also, do I need to set a proxy? How? and what credentials should I be giving it since I'm working on localhost?

Comment: Oh shoot.  I linked the wrong article I had open, sorry.  Basically they changed the links in platforms.js (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova) to use http instead of the default https.  I mean this is really a workaround than solution, but it might get you going for now.

Comment: @laughingpine no luck either :(! there's only one entry in that platforms.js file including https.. plus it's a comment actually so I don't think it's a big deal.. Yet I edited it but the error is still the same.. I'm really out of options :( :(

Comment: It's obvious here that something's blocking your connection. Can you reach [GitHub](http://github.com) properly?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply and help @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ .. I can reach Github properly yes.. Any thoughts on what could be blocking the connection ?

Comment: @SalwaGeo Where are you located?

Comment: I'm located in Morocco

Comment: No I don't get any security warning.. I just pasted the url on the browser and got this page with json code..

Comment: @SalwaGeo Do you experience a security warning when attempting to navigate to `https://registry.npmjs.org/mongojs`?

Comment: @SalwaGeo What browser are you using? If it's Internet Explorer, try with Google Chrome since IE doesn't show the warnings.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome indeed

Comment: No other answers? :( I'm starting to feel hopeless with this issue.. In the meanwhile I've started reading about Sencha Touch but I figured out that I will ultimately use Cordova to deploy the app in case I decided to go for Sencha Touch :( So technically I will face this issue no matter what !!?

Comment: Is there an alternative to cordova while trying to deploy a sencha touch application?? Please help

Comment: Hmm its really weird. Did you try to install it by disabling the firewall?

Comment: Did you try with windows command or git-bash? Try running the cmd in "run as admin" mode

Comment: First of all thank u for ur reply @Senthil. It is weird indeed. and yes I tried to install it by disabling the firewall : same error.. I also tried using the cmd in run as an admin : still the same error ! :(

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

or

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

If that seems to work then it has to do with the self-signed certificate on the server in question.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply @Michael Blankenship. I did tried both commands but none of them worked... What could be wrong in ur opinion?

Comment: At least you can rule out that 1) the server has a bad certificate or 2) your local browser isn't missing some Certificate of Authority root.

Comment: I don't think I'd add the proxy-related variables if I weren't behind a proxy.

Comment: @Andy There's an actual difference between the words "could" and "might".  They both indicate that the individual has the power to choose whether or not to take the suggestion.  The latter indicates some reservation about the effectiveness of same.

Comment: Yeah, it was a suggested edit by another user that I modified formatting on.  I'll revert it to might

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship sorry for my late response. I didn't get it. How would I know if the server has a bad certificate? or the local browser is missing some certificate of authority root.. I'm confused..

Comment: Well I deleted them proxy-related variables afterwards.. still no luck!

Comment: Has any one of u figured a solution to this problem ?! Any help is much appreciated